# Loading some XML into JSON in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, xml, converters

I am new to NodeJS and trying to figure out **how to load some xml data from a REST service** and convert it to JSON so I can afterwards load it into my view.

I'm trying to do so querying with `Hapi` API and **loading it into an xml parser then convert it to JSON**.

Doing the following seems loading correctly the xml object and when printing it it actually shows me some JSON. **Does it mean that I don't need to convert to JSON anymore?**

```
const server = new Hapi.Server();
...
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        Request.get('http://ws.seloger.com/search.xml?&idtt=2&idtypebien=2,1&ci=750056&pxmax=400000&tri=initial&naturebien=1,2&surfacemin=65search.xml?',
            function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            var parse = require('xml-parser');
            var inspect = require('util').inspect;    
            var obj = parse(body);
            console.log(inspect(obj, { colors: true, depth: 4 }));
```

Note that the JSON displayed is also not what I am looking for, ie. showing the details with `attributes`, `children`, etc.:

```
{ declaration: { attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'UTF-8' } },
root: 
{ name: 'recherche',
    attributes: {},
    children: 
    [ { name: 'resume',
        attributes: {},
        children: [],
        content: '....' },
```

However looking for something more like [this](http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/438/leagueTable) (might be just a different representation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that my issue seemed to have been related to the parser itself. Using this one I get what I need:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
parseString(body, function (err, jsonData) {
    reply.view('index', { result: body });
});
```